# passing a variable to the replace_str mehtod in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that i can pass strings to the `replace_str` method in javascript.

But what i really want is to be able to pass variables to make it dynamic. The problem is, every time i try to pass a variable to the method it doesn't work.

I'm coming from php and it's pretty easy to do it with the `substr_replace();` method. Now what is the equivalent in javascript.

Here is my code:

```html
<p>Click to test the result.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  
    var full_string = "http://ok.ru/video/42597812745";
    var code = full_string.substr(19, 11);

    //Testing if this is working
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = code;

    r_frame = '<iframe width="600" height="400" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/41680046601" frameborder="0"   allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    var str_to_be_replaced = r_frame.substr(57, 11);
    //Testing if this is working
    //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str_to_be_replaced;
  
  var res = str.replace(code, str_to_be_replaced);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  //Not working
}
```

```html
<p>Click to test the result.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What is the value of `str`?

Comment: yeap, it would probably need to be `var res = r_frame.replace(code, str_to_be_replaced);` instead

Comment: `str.replace()` has a quirk, if the needle is a String, only a RegExp with the global-flag set replaces all occurances of that pattern. You may want to use this instead `str.split(code).join(str_to_be_replaced)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of what you were trying to accomplish, I gather that you want to replace the url of a `src` attribute. I made a function that uses [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`regex`](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) to search and replace for:

`src="`<kbd>this is to be replaced</kbd>`"`

This is the heart of the Snippet:

```
var str = str.replace(/src\=['"][^'"]*['"]/g, 'src="' + rep + '"');
```

**Snippet**

```js
var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
var inp1 = document.getElementById('inp1');
var inp2 = document.getElementById('inp2');
var inp3 = document.getElementById('inp3');

inp1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var str = inp2.value;
  var rep = inp3.value;
  var res = swapSrc(str, rep);
  out1.textContent = res.toString();
}, false);


function swapSrc(str, rep) {
  var str = str.replace(/src\=['"][^'"]*['"]/g, 'src="' + rep + '"');
  console.log(str);
  return str;
}

//var str = '<iframe width="600" height="400" src="//ok.ru/videoembed/41680046601" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

//var rep = '//ok.ru/video/42597812745';
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 14px/1.45'Verdana';
  background: #333;
  color: #fc3;
}
fieldset {
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
legend {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
input {
  width: 30ex;
  font: inherit;
  color: #000;
}
label:last-of-type {
  font-size: .75em;
}
output {
  color: #e0e;
  font-family: 'Consolas'
}
code {
  background: darkblue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Test the provided strings below or enter your own<span class="red">*</span></legend>
  <input id="inp2" value="<iframe width='600' height='400' src='//ok.ru/videoembed/41680046601' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>" />&nbsp;
  <input id="inp3" value="//ok.ru/video/42597812745" />&nbsp;
  <button id="inp1">TEST</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label for="out1">New String:
    <output id="out1"></output>
  </label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label><span class="red">*</span>Do not wrap data in quotes</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Exactly  what i'm trying to do, but i will generalize it to include more servers e.g uptobox, youwatch.org, vidizi.tv and so on. And i will definitely use some of your code. Thanks bud.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped, you can still upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do `var res = str.replace(code, str_to_be_replaced);` but there is not `str` variable defined anywhere..

I think what you want is either

```
var res = full_string.replace(code, str_to_be_replaced);
```

or

```
var res = r_frame.replace(str_to_be_replaced, code);
```

Comment: Thanks Gaby, it worked. But when i try to apply the toString(); method to it. It doesn't work. Please note that i want to get only the string representation of the iframe.

Comment: You mean you want to display the actual iframe code and not embed it in the page ? Then use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` like this `document.getElementById("demo").textContent= res;`

Comment: Thanks again, Gaby. I really appreciate you help. Keep it up buddy.